# How to configure MPEG-TS playback through Haali Media Splitter and ffdshow on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mpeg

In Windows 7, in effort to enhance HTTV playback, I suppose, they added MPEG-TS container support. However I'd love to play such streams using ffdshow as it supports infinite number of tweaks.

How could I configure Windows to play TS through Haali and ffdshow? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use FFDShow without Haali in most cases. Just turn up the merit on FFDShow (either through it's control panel or a third-party utility).

You can force Windows to use Haali by using a third-party utility to turn up its merit as well.